# using a list to create a histogram bar graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram

Let me start by saying I know about the histogram function that just creates a nice histogram from a list of data. For this project I am trying to do everything the somewhat hard way because as far as I am concerned, more code=more practice.

Now for the meat of the question, with plenty of help I have managed to write code that extracts a data set, takes user inputs for titles and number of bins, and crunches everything accurately into a "histogram" list, something like `[1,3,5,3,1]` with the numbers corresponding to the frequency of a range of data.

What I am trying to do from this point is take that histogram list and place it in a bar graph using `plt.bar()`. I have some familiarity with `plt.scatter()` but it seems bar works differently as

```
plt.bar(x, y, align='center')
plt.xticks(y)
plt.show
```

with x being a list containing the separation values for the bins, and y being the list of frequencies, simply returns an empty graph. any assistance would be appreciated.

Edit: code modifications:

```
column="voltage"
y=[14, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 9] # frequencies
x=[-4.9183599999999998, -3.916083, -2.9138060000000001, -1.9115290000000003, 
-0.90925200000000039, 0.093024999999999025, 1.0953019999999993, 
2.0975789999999996, 3.0998559999999991, 4.1021329999999985, 
5.1044099999999979] #bin limits
z=range(len(y))
plt.bar(z, y, 1.0)
plt.xlabel("%s" %column)
plt.xticks(z, x)
plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image]

Pretty close, eventually I'll need to round x, but before that happens, how do I get the ticks to align to the right? Also, why is the xlabel line outputting "1" instead of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre `show` is missing some `()` - and your code does not qualify as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

This works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [1,1,4,7,4,3]

x = range(len(y))

plt.bar(x, y, 0.75, color="blue")
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot 1]

---

Your y and x have  different dimensions, they will be cropped to the shorter one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

column="voltage"
y=[14, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 9] # frequencies
x=[-4.9183599999999998, -3.916083, -2.9138060000000001, -1.9115290000000003, 
-0.90925200000000039, 0.093024999999999025, 1.0953019999999993, 
2.0975789999999996, 3.0998559999999991, 4.1021329999999985, 
5.1044099999999979] #bin limits
z=range(len(y))

plt.bar(z, y, 0.8)
plt.xlabel("%s" %column) 

plt.xticks(z,[str(round(i,4)) for i in x], rotation=35) # round, label and use

plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot 2]

I adjusted the subplot borders in the popup, you need to code that. How to and how to move all bars to the right so they are between the ticks, see:

[Move graph position within plot (matplotlib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561622/move-graph-position-within-plot-matplotlib)

Thats too much matplotmagic for me.

Comment: Thanks for the mvce tip, hopefully my edit is better.

Comment: @a.f.uwrf A mvce: I can copy your code into my IDE and it runs (or produces the error). See edit for labeling and link for moving. Putting question after question after question into one is considered bad. Accept an answer and if you have new questions, ask them. Its bad because anybody looking for "how to change label on xaxis" wont find your questionsin search b/c title is about 'using a list to create a histogram bar graph' - so this part of knowledge is buried and mislabeld.